# MessageBox Buttons?

Tags: c#, button, messagebox

How would I say if the yes button on the messagebox was pressed do this,that and the other? In C#.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

1. Your call to `MessageBox.Show` needs to pass `MessageBoxButtons.YesNo` to get the <kbd>Yes</kbd>/<kbd>No</kbd> buttons instead of the <kbd>OK</kbd> button.
2. Compare the result of that call (which will block execution until the dialog returns) to `DialogResult.Yes`....

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    // user clicked yes
}
else
{
    // user clicked no
}
```

Comment: @xxMUROxx Please do not edit answers to refactor code. If you feel the need to add additional content with improvements, either leave a comment or add your own answer.

Answer (score 12):

If you actually want Yes and No buttons (and assuming WinForms):

```
void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var message = "Yes or No?";
    var title = "Hey!";
    var result = MessageBox.Show(
        message,                  // the message to show
        title,                    // the title for the dialog box
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,  // show two buttons: Yes and No
        MessageBoxIcon.Question); // show a question mark icon

    // the following can be handled as if/else statements as well
    switch (result)
    {
    case DialogResult.Yes:   // Yes button pressed
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed Yes!");
        break;
    case DialogResult.No:    // No button pressed
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed No!");
        break;
    default:                 // Neither Yes nor No pressed (just in case)
        MessageBox.Show("What did you press?");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if(DialogResult.OK==MessageBox.Show("Do you Agree with me???"))
{
         //do stuff if yess
}
else
{
         //do stuff if No
}
```

Comment: This won't work as espected, 'cause the sentences in the else won't be called anytime.

Comment: @james_bond: Close the dialog and check for else part.

Comment: If you're not using one of the `Show` overloads containing the `MessageBoxButtons` parameter, the `MessageBox` will not have any button other than Ok, so the `else` part will never be triggered. Even if you close it via the close box in the top right corner, the result is `DialogResult.OK`.

Answer (score 2):

An updated version of the correct answer for .NET 4.5 would be.

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Confirm", MessageBoxImage.Question) 
    == MessageBoxResult.Yes)  
{
// If yes
}
else  
{
// If no
}
```

Additionally, if you wanted to bind the button to a command in a view model you could use the following. This is compatible with MvvmLite:

```
public RelayCommand ShowPopUpCommand
{
   get
   {
   return _showPopUpCommand ??
      (_showPopUpCommand = new RelayCommand(
         () =>
               {
                // Put if statement here
               }
      }));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
                     if (
 MessageBox.Show(@"Are you Alright?", @"My Message Box",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        //YES ---> Ok IM ALRIGHHT
                    }
                    else
                   {
                   //NO --->NO IM STUCK
                    }
```

Regards

Answer (score -1):

This way to check the condition while pressing 'YES' or 'NO' buttons in MessageBox window.

```
DialogResult d = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure ?", "Remove Panel", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (d == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                //Contents
            }
            else if (d == DialogResult.No)
            {
                //Contents
            }
```